# How to create a Mongodb Distinct search with a filter?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa

I was looking to create a distinct search in a MongoDB collection with a filter condition.
The collection is alertStatus with the following format:

```json
{ 'id' : 0, 'group' : "groupe1", 'state' : "PENDING" }
{ 'id' : 1, 'group' : "groupe2", 'state' : "PENDING" }
{ 'id' : 2, 'group' : "groupe3", 'state' : "DONE" }
{ 'id' : 3, 'group' : "groupe2", 'state' : "PENDING" }
```

I want the list of different groups where the state is "PENDING"

Here is a **working solution** for Java/SpringBoot :

```java
@Autowired
protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  DistinctIterable<String> groups = mongoTemplate.getCollection("alertStatus")
                .distinct("group",String.class)
                .filter(new Document("state","PENDING"));

  for ( String g : groups) {
     log.info(g);
  }
```

If someone has a solution using JPA, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to do the same query using Repositories in Spring?